# Dynamic implementation of an Interface

Tags: c#

Suppose I have an Interface with some properties:

```
public interface IDummy
{
    string First  {get;set;}
    string Second {get;set;}
    string Third  {get;set;}
    string Fourth {get;set;}
}
```

Now, I have a class which implements that interface:

```
public class DummyClass: IDummy
{
    // ...
}
```

Is it possible, not to implement the interface properties explicitly and instead use DynamicObject? For example:

```
public class DummyClass: DynamicObject, IDummy
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        // Get the value from a Config file or SQLite db or something
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        // Get the value to a Config file or SQLite db or something
    }
}
```

I am just curious if this is possible or not?
Thanks.

Comment: Well you could just try it and see if it works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you are implementing an interface, you need to implement all of its members. C# is still a statically typed language, after all.

When you say a type implements an interface, you are saying it conforms to its contract. Not implementing all of the members means that you are *not* complying with the contract.

The compiler would see your code and will not assume that you have implemented the contract correctly (in a dynamic fashion) - it will fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

No, basically. An interface is for static typing; to satisfy an interface your type must actually provide a regular (non-dynamic) implementation. You could *not claim to implement it* (IDummy), and detect the names, but that could relate to any interface that uses those same names, not just IDummy.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a wrapper.

```
class DummyWrapper : IDummy
{
    private readonly DynamicObject _wrapped;

    public DummyWrapper(DynamicObject wrapped)
    {
        _wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    string First
    {
        get { return _wrapped.First; }
        set { _wrapped.First = value; }
    }

    string Second
    {
        get { return _wrapped.Second; }
        set { _wrapped.Second = value; }
    }

    string Third
    {
        get { return _wrapped.Third; }
        set { _wrapped.Third = value; }
    }

    string Fourth
    {
        get { return _wrapped.Fourth; }
        set { _wrapped.Fourth = value; }
    }
}
```

You might also be interested in these questions:

- [Automatically creating a wrapper to implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920222/automatically-creating-a-wrapper-to-implement-an-interface)
- [Dynamically implementing an interface in .NET 4.0 (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974736/dynamically-implementing-an-interface-in-net-4-0-c)