# Can I create a wrapper that intercept all calls to objects implementing certain interface?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, interface

Let's say I have an interface IFoo

```
interface IFoo
{
  int Bar();
  int Bar2();
  void VBar();
  //etc,
}
```

Can I create a wrapper that takes any IFoo object and do something before/after the actual call?

e.g. when I do something like this

```
IFoo wrappedFoo = new Wrapper<IFoo>(actualFooObject).Object;
wrappedFoo.Bar();
```

then the wrapper.Bar() method actually execute something like this

```
PreCall(); //some code that I can define in the wrapper
actualFooObject.Bar();
PostCall();
```

Is there a simple and clean way to do this?

Comment: `Wrapper<IFoo>` doesn't make much sense to me, since you want to be able to write `wrapper.Bar()`...all these methods must therefore be defined in `Wrapper<T>`, but they are `T`-specific. Seems to me that you need to make `IFooWrapper` implement `IFoo`, and do so for each interface. That would mean to write the same `Precall(); object.Bar; Postcall()` for all `Bar` methods, which is not simple and clean :-)

Comment: @caerolus you're right, Wrapper<IFoo> doesn't make sense. Maybe we can still keep the generic-ness by defining `T Object { get; }` property for `Wrapper<T>`, similar to `mock.Object` in `Moq`.

Comment: But doing something like `IFoo wrappedFoo = new Wrapper<IFoo>(actualFooObject).Object;` you're just ignoring the wrapper... `wrappedFoo` would just point to the original object!

Comment: This might be useful as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920222/automatically-creating-a-wrapper-to-implement-an-interface?rq=1 and this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847809/how-can-i-write-a-generic-container-class-that-implements-a-given-interface-in-c/847975#847975

Comment: @caerolus not necessarily, the property object can return something else (not the original object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) for this approach. Take a look on section `2.8 Interface Contracts` of [user manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) (pdf).

Comment: you mean instead of defining contract, I can write my custom code in the contract class?

Comment: Sorry, I actually forgot that they are really primitive.. You can try to write your own contracts and override defaults, but anyway this will be really primitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP. I´ve been using this library for quite some time now:

http://www.postsharp.net/products

Answer (score 0):

if you need to have something on `PreCall()` and `PostCall` , the simple way is to wrap under the proxy base approach

```
  public abstract class ProxyBase
  {
    public void Execute()
    {
      PreCondition();
      Call();
      PostCondition();
    }
    private void PreCondition()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("ProxyBase.PreCondition()");
    }
    private void PostCondition()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("ProxyBase.PreCondition()");
    }
    protected abstract void Call();
  }
  public class AppProxy<T> : ProxyBase where T : IApp
  {
    private IApp _app;

    public AppProxy<T> Init(IApp app)
    {
      _app = app;
      return this;
    }

    protected override void Call()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("AppProxy.Call()");
      _app.Call();
    }

    public IApp Object
    {
      get { return _app; }
    }
  }

  public interface IApp
  {
    void Call();
  }

  public interface IFoo : IApp
  {

  }

  public class ActualFoo : IApp
  {
    public void Call()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("ActualFoo.Call()");
    }
  }

 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ActualFoo actualFoo = new ActualFoo();
      var app = new AppProxy<IFoo>().Init(actualFoo);
      app.Execute();
      var o = app.Object as ActualFoo;

      Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
```

--------------- Output --------------
ProxyBase.PreCondition()
AppProxy.Call()
ActualFoo.Call()
ProxyBase.PreCondition()

Comment: But then he'll basically have to write the same code for each `Call`-like method in his `IFoo` interface. This is far from simple and clean

Comment: Also, note that you cannot do `app.Call` or similar

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a "clean and simple" way of doing this.

The best option I can come up with is writing a generic `Wrapper<T>` that encapsulates and instance of `T` and implements generic `Precall` and `Postcall` methods:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    protected T _instance;
    public Wrapper(T instance)
    {
        this._instance = instance;
    }
    protected virtual void Precall()
    {
        // do something
    }
    protected virtual void Postcall()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

So that you can write your own `FooWrapper` for interface `IFoo` (or any other interface) and just delegate method calls:

```
public class FooWrapper :Wrapper<IFoo>, IFoo
{
    public FooWrapper(IFoo foo)
        : base(foo)
    {
    }
    public int Bar()
    {
        base.Precall(); return base._instance.Bar(); base.Postcall();
    }
    public int Bar2()
    {
        base.Precall(); return base._instance.Bar2(); base.Postcall();
    }
    public void VBar()
    {
        base.Precall();  base._instance.VBar(); base.Postcall();
    }
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
IFoo f = new ActualFooClass();
IFoo wf = new FooWrapper(f);
f.Bar();
```

Of course, if your `Precall` and `Postcall` methods are not generic, then there is really no point in using the `Wrapper<T>` class. Just go with the `FooWrapper`.