# How to compare complex objects as structures in C# for Unit Tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I came across the following problem:
Currently I'm refactoring my project using TDD. There is an existed domain that I can't change.

Code example:

```
public class Product: IEquatable<Product>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        if (Id == other.Id && Name == other.Name)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class ProductTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var product1 = new Product {Id = 100, Name = "iPhone"};
        var product2 = new Product {Id = 100, Name = "iPhone"};
        Assert.IsTrue(product1.Equals(product2));
    }
}
```

My goal is to find a quick solution to compare complex objects as structures and not implement IEquatable cause I can't extend bussiness layer. I mean something like Automapper but not to map but just to compare. Please, give some advices.

Thank in advance.

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986572/hows-to-quick-check-if-data-transfer-two-objects-have-equal-properties-in-c/986617#986617 or:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060382/comparing-2-objects-and-retrive-a-list-of-fields-with-different-values/3060929#3060929

Answer (score 4):

Using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986572/hows-to-quick-check-if-data-transfer-two-objects-have-equal-properties-in-c/986617#986617) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060382/comparing-2-objects-and-retrive-a-list-of-fields-with-different-values/3060929#3060929):

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public static class ProductTest
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var product1 = new Product { Id = 100, Name = "iPhone" };
        var product2 = new Product { Id = 100, Name = "iPhone" };
        bool x = PropertyCompare.Equal(product1, product2); // true

        var deltas = PropertyComparer<Product>.GetDeltas(product1, product2);
        // ^^= an empty list
    }
}
```

changing the second `Name` to `"iPhone2"` gives `false` and a list containing the single entry: `"Name"`.