# Pattern/technique for sending ‘updated only fields’ from server to client for a given object?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, network-programming, protobuf-net

I have some serverside data that I need replicating (pushed in real-time) from a server app to around 100 wpf clients. My problem is when a given Order object changes it typically only changes a 1 or 2 fields so I only want to send those changes over the wire Not the whole object – thus decreasing the wire payload, processing time etc as the whole Order object has around 50 fields.

The data is a Dictionary of Order objects keyed on OrderId. I use protobuf-net to seralise the data and send over the wire to the wpf clients.

Has anyone dealt with this patterm/problem before? Or have any ideas on who to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple proxy using Castle.DynamicProxy which saves the name of all properties that have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

protobuf-net supports a number of patterns to aid this type of scenario, the simplest being (to share the pattern used by System.ComponentModel):

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public string Foo { get;set; }

public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() { /* return true if Foo is "dirty" */ }
```

This assumes you have some mechanism for tracking the changes *yourself* (for hooking into the `ShouldSerialize*` method); protobuf-net doesn't do change tracking itself. If you don't currently have any change tracking, you might be able to use something from this answer: [Comparing 2 objects and retrieve a list of fields with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060382/comparing-2-objects-and-retrive-a-list-of-fields-with-different-values/3060929#3060929)

Comment: Sorry how would this work? I can track changes using INotifyPropertyChanged and store the last change in a Hashtable (key: PropertyName, Value = theValue). But in your example, how would ShouldSerializeFoo be used? Inside the property?

Comment: Also do you have any System.ComponentModel examples? I can't find anything on this usage pattern?

Comment: @arkina - [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.shouldserializevalue.aspx) for MSDN discussing that pattern. Re your earlier comment, I might use a `HashSet<string>` and just store the names; "as is" the object would need to be able to return `true`/`false` on a member-by-member basis, i.e. `return deltas.Contains("Foo")`

Comment: I meant a Dictionary (hashtable) (key: PropertyName, Value = theValue) to store the property name and latest values

Comment: @arkina fine, whatever works; as long as you can tell whether it has changed or not.