# How to check if properties of two objects are equal

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have two objects using the ff. class:

```
public class Test {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Input> Inputs {get;set;}
    ......
    //some other properties I don't need to check
}

public class Input {
    public int VariableA {get;set;}
    public int VariableB {get;set;}
    public List<Sancti> Sancts {get;set;}
}

public class Sancti {
    public string Symbol {get;set;}
    public double Percentage {get;set;}
}
```

I want to check if two instance of `Test` has the same `Inputs` value. I've done this using a loop but I believe this is not the way to do this.

I've read some links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060382/comparing-2-objects-and-retrieve-a-list-of-fields-with-different-values) but they seem gibberish for me. Are there simpler ways to do this, like a one-liner something like:

`test1.Inputs.IsTheSameAs(test2.Inputs)`?

I was really hoping for a more readable method. Preferrably `Linq`.

**NOTE:** Order of inputs should not matter.

Comment: Does ordering of Inputs matter?

Comment: should not matter.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c

Comment: Since you are comparing two lists, it depends on how you are defining "the same". For instance, are two lists considered the same or different if they have all the same values, but the two lists are in entirely different orders? That your list contains objects that themselves contain a list, compounds the problem exponentially.

Comment: @Kevin, ordering of `Inputs` shouldn't matter. Two Lists are not equal if any of the properties(*or count*) of `Input` or `Sancti` are not equal with the other list

Comment: @Fran, does `SequenceEqual` do a deep search?

Comment: I'm not sure.  You'd probably have to implement IEqualityComparer at every level and make sure the parent level called SequenceEqual in the implementation.

Comment: But for `SequenceEqual` to return true,the elements should be in the same order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `Input` and `Sancti` class definitions to override `Equals` and `GetHasCode`. The following solution considers that 2 Inputs are equal when:

1. `VariableA` are equal and
2. `VariableB` are equal and
3. The `Sancts` List are equal, considering that the `Sancti` elements with the same `Symbol` must have the same `Percentage` to be equal

You may need to change this if your specifications are different:

```
public class Input
{
    public int VariableA { get; set; }
    public int VariableB { get; set; }
    public List<Sancti> Sancts { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Input otherInput = obj as Input;
        if (ReferenceEquals(otherInput, null))
            return false;
        if ((this.VariableA == otherInput.VariableA) && 
            (this.VariableB == otherInput.VariableB) && 
            this.Sancts.OrderBy(x=>x.Symbol).SequenceEqual(otherInput.Sancts.OrderBy(x => x.Symbol)))
            return true;
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + VariableA.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + VariableB.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + Sancts.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}

public class Sancti
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public double Percentage { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Sancti otherInput = obj as Sancti;
        if (ReferenceEquals(otherInput, null))
            return false;
        if ((this.Symbol == otherInput.Symbol) && (this.Percentage == otherInput.Percentage) )
            return true;
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + Symbol.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + Percentage.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this, you just have to do this to check if `Input`s are equal:

```
test1.Inputs.SequenceEqual(test2.Inputs);
```

Comment: this works. I just tweaked it to my specifications. thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way is to check the set negation between the two lists. If the result of `listA` negated by `listB` has no elements, that means that everything in `listA` exists in `listB`. If the reverse is also true, then the two lists are equal.

```
bool equal = testA.Inputs.Except(testB.Inputs).Count() == 0 
             && testB.Inputs.Except(testA.Inputs).Count() == 0;
```

Another is to simply check each element of `listA` and see if it exists in `listB` (and vice versa):

```
bool equal = testA.Inputs.All(x => testB.Inputs.Contains(x)) 
             && testB.Inputs.All(x => testA.Inputs.Contains(x));
```

This being said, either of these can throw a false positive if there is one element in a list that would be "equal" to multiple elements in the other. For example, the following two lists would be considered equal using the above approaches:

```
listA = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
listB = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 };
```

To prevent that from happening, you would need to perform a one-to-one search rather than the nuclear solution. There are several ways to do this, but one way to do this is to first sort both lists and then checking their indices against each other:

```
var listASorted = testA.Inputs.OrderBy(x => x);
var listBSorted = testB.Inputs.OrderBy(x => x);
bool equal = testA.Inputs.Count == testB.Inputs.Count
             && listASorted.Zip(listBSorted, (x, y) => x == y).All(b => b);
```

*(If the lists are already sorted or if you'd prefer to check the lists exactly (with ordering preserved), then you can skip the sorting step of this method.)*

One thing to note with this method, however, is that `Input` needs to implement `IComparable` in order for them to be properly sorted. How you implement it exactly is up to you, but one possible way would be to sort `Input` based on the XOR of `VariableA` and `VariableB`:

```
public class Input : IComparable<Input> 
{
    ...

    public int Compare(Input other)
    {
        int a = this.VariableA ^ this.VariableB;
        int b = other.VariableA ^ other.VariableB;
        return a.Compare(b);
    }
}
```

*(In addition, `Input` should also override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, as itsme86 describes in his answer.)*

**EDIT:**

After being drawn back to this answer, I would now like to offer a much simpler solution:

```
var listASorted = testA.Inputs.OrderBy(x => x);
var listBSorted = testB.Inputs.OrderBy(x => x);
bool equal = listASorted.SequenceEqual(listBSorted);
```

*(As before, you can skip the sorting step if the lists are already sorted or you want to compare them with their existing ordering intact.)*

`SequenceEqual` uses the equality comparer for a particular type for determining equality. By default, this means checking that the values of all public properties are equal between two objects. If you want to implement a different approach, you can define an `IEqualityComparer` for `Input`:

```
public class InputComparer : IEqualityComparer<Input>
{
    public bool Equals(Input a, Input b)
    {
        return a.variableA == b.variableA
            && a.variableB == b.variableB
            && ... and so on
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Input a)
    {
        return a.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```